# vim: jumping with CTRL-O doesn't get me back to netrw

Tags: vim

Suppose I'm editing file **a.txt** on a buffer, then run `:E.` and from the netrw open another file, say **b.txt**.

Now if I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, I'm back on **a.txt** and not into the netrw explorer.

`:jumps` has not registered the Netrw location. Is there any way to make netrw dir locations to be registered as jumps, and hence make <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> work as I expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your scenario, and it worked for me.  Nonetheless, perhaps you'll find

> :Rex

will do what you want.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want, i will use it from now on. If I open vim with no file, open netrw, edit a new file from there, CTRL-O does work as expected, but if I run vim from the shell to edit any file, then explore current folder and open another file, CTRL-O gets me back to the initial file, it's very confusing. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think the canonical solution is to `let g:netrw_keepj=""`

```
  *g:netrw_keepj*       ="keepj" (default) netrw attempts to keep the
                         |:jumps| table unaffected.
                =""      netrw will not use |:keepjumps| with
                     exceptions only for the
                     saving/restoration of position.
```